# Select from dropdown, edit and update in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a dropdown with physician names in it. I want be able to select a physician from the dropdown, click edit and be taken to the edit page for the physician.

In my routes :

```
  resources :physicians, only: [:index, :new, :create, :update]
  get '/physicians/edit', to: 'physicians#edit'
```

In my physician controller:

```
def update
 @physician = Physician.find(params[:id])

 respond_to do |format|
  if @physican.update_attributes(physician_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @physican, info: 'Physician was successfully updated.' }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
  end
 end
end
def physician_params
  params.require(:physician).permit(:office_id, :user_id, :full_name, :prefix, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :suffix, :primary)
end
```

In my physician index:

```
  <%= form_tag '/physicians/edit', :method => :get do %>

    <%= select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@physicians, :id, :first_name),
                       prompt: 'Choose one', id: 'physician_select', class: 'form-control option-large' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Edit', class: 'btn' %>
  <% end %>
```

In my _form.edit.html.erb

```
<div class="center" role="form">
<%= form_tag physician_path(@physician), :method => :patch do %>

  <div class="form-group space">
    <%= label_tag :first_name %>
    <%= text_field_tag :first_name, params[:first_name], class: 'form-control' %>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group space">
    <%= link_to '', root_path, class: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Update Physician', class: 'btn btn-warning pull-add-btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Error when trying to update the :first_name attribute:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in PhysiciansController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: physician
```

The value for first_name is there and it's been whitelisted too. I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: Do you have the :first_name permitted in physician_params? Can you share the physician_params method?

Comment: I've updated the physician controller to show the permitted params.

Comment: I see that you have moved to form_for, which is good. In the above form_tag code, removing require(:physician) might do the trick - in the form_tag case, there is no physician key in the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) over `form_tag` in this case since you are updating a resource. `form_tag` is really best used for creating a resource via POST, but even then `form_for` is a more convenient solution.

Your code becomes:

```
<%= form_for @physician do |f| %>    
  <div class="form-group space">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group space">
    <%= link_to '', root_path, class: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Update Physician', class: 'btn btn-warning pull-add-btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I actually like this better. Made the change and now get this error:
NoMethodError in PhysiciansController#update
undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Your `Physician.find(params[:id])` lookup is coming back as `nil` for some reason. Check the params in the request to make sure you're receiving a valid ID for a physician in your database.

Comment: 'Parameters:

    {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "_method"=>"patch",
             "authenticity_token"=>"xUdMnoBNFj7rTwq1tYag/59gfK0ce+ssQQBhxVUK    wIWghJOOkXn+Sd1kiQ9ovjF6icXY/xONq159EeKBNU/kEQ==",
     "physician"=>{"first_name"=>"GEORGE"},
     "commit"=>"Update Physician",
     "id"=>"17"}'

Comment: Are you sure you changed `submit_tag` to `f.submit`?

Comment: Yes. I'm using f.submit instead of submit_tag. In my update action, I found a typo in my instance variable @physician, which is why I was getting that error.

Comment: Yes. Also, had to change my redirect to "/physicians/" for my redirect_to to work correctly. Thanks for all the help.